# Out of stock button instead of Add to cart if quantity is not in stock

Tags: php, opencart

I had given the below code a try and it also worked but what i feel it made my website unstable, i.e sometimes cart success popsup on 1st click, sometimes on 2-3 clicks, sometimes it doesnot pop up. :-(

What i wanted to achieve was: If quantity is <0, Add to cart button text is replaced by "Out of stock"

In my theme's product.tpl, i made the following change,

replaced the below line

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="button-cart" class="button-product-page" />
```

with below code

```
<?php if ($stock == "In Stock") { echo '<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="button-cart" class="button-product-page" />'; } else { echo '<input type="button" value="Out Of Stock" class="button-product-page"/>'; } ?>
```

Please let me know if any modifications or fine tuning required in above code.

Comment: Did you test it? does it work?

I'm not sure if you expect us to test it for you :)

If something doesn't work, let us know.

Comment: Yes it did work exactly. I have also said above that it worked the way i wanted...But it caused some issues as stated above.

Comment: this change (if made correctly) can't make your website unstable, may be you were unable the change it correctly. if you apply this change directly in tpl in fresh opencart it will work fine. try if there are some errors in vqmod or your browser console